# Windows Mail file extensions

Tags: windows, email

Anybody happen to know the file extension(s) for the Address Books in Windows Mail, or even better, where they may be located?

Comment: Thanks, and yes it was for backup purposes. Unfortunately the user does wants to stick with Windows Mail. What can you do?

Answer (score 1):

The Mail Is located under:

C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Mail\Local Folders

and uses the extension .eml

contacts are saved under

C:\Users[USERNAME]\Contacts

and are saved as a .contact file

Comment: exactly. but don't use windows mail. many viruses are created specifically for it

Comment: I believe his intent was to back up windows mail, probably to prepare for a move to a better client?

Comment: you can't do much to turn them, try to find out what they don't like about windows mail that another client does well. A good example is contact searching is broken in windows mail, but is pretty amazing in thunderbird. that's how I won a customer over.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mail stores contacts as .contact files in C:\Users\username\Contacts

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows Vista, try looking at these locations:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Mail\Local Folders

C:\Users\username\Contacts

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Mail

Comment: file extension of .contact